# How to show hand cursor on a datagrid header?

Tags: apache-flex

Is it possible that when mouse is over the datagrid header the cursor changes to hand cursor instead of the pointer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do that directly without extending datagrid as i don't believe there's any way to directly access the header. We do fortunately have the height of the header available to us and can compare it to the mouse position to change the cursor manually. Here's a complete example in flex4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               applicationComplete="init()"
               >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        private function init():void{
            this.grid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function():void{
                if (grid.contentMouseY <= grid.headerHeight) {
                    useHandCursor = true
                    buttonMode = true
                } else {
                    useHandCursor = false
                    buttonMode = false
                }
            })
            this.grid.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function():void {
                useHandCursor = false
                buttonMode = false
            })
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid id="grid"/>
</s:Application>
```

Here's the flash doc on creating / extending flex3 components(since its an mx component): http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part4_CreateComps_1.html